# Errors when attempting to use a Shim for Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicebus, shim

I am using QueueClient to send messages over the Azure Service Bus using code based on some examples found on msdn:

- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Brokered-Messaging-Request-2b4ff5d8/sourcecode?fileId=123790&pathId=168550149
- and another link that I can't show here due to my reputation, but it can be found  via https at code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Session-41c43fb4/sourcecode?fileId=124692&pathId=317475279

I actually have working code with the QueueClient, but I wanted to make some unit tests. That's where the problems start. I'm having problems shimming the Microsoft classes.

My code will accept a QueueClient and use it to send the messages. My first pass at creating a unit test for that code was to try and create and test a shim of the QueueClient. I did so with a detour for the Send(BrokeredMessage) method, a call to that method on the shim, and an assertion that my detour was called.

Some fiddling was involved - QueueClient is abstract and doesn't implement any Interfaces AND I had to create a instance to shim using the create method with a fake path. I don't know if that might cause problems when running the test.

I ended up with the following test:

```
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

... [some context removed]

        [TestMethod]
    public void TestFireAndForgetHappyPath2()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            const string messageBody = "Hi";
            string capturedBody = null;

            var shimmedClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://fake.net/;", "queueName");

            var shim = new Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Fakes.ShimQueueClient(shimmedClient)
            {
                SendBrokeredMessage = message => { capturedBody = message.GetBody<string>(); }
            };

            shim.SendBrokeredMessage(new BrokeredMessage(messageBody));
            Assert.AreEqual(messageBody, capturedBody);
        }
    }
```

I created the code in Visual Studio. It doesn't complain (i.e. no red squiggles) in the editor, but when I try to build, I get the following error:

> The property or indexer
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Fakes.ShimQueueClient.SendBrokeredMessage'  cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

I looked for examples in Microsoft's Shim documentation. They even have an example related to the service bus, but they don't use a QueueClient. Instead they use a class and interface that I can't find in MSDN (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh873028.aspx and its use of IMicrosoftAzureQueue).

Can somebody provide some examples on how to properly stub/mock/shim the QueueClient?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is the line that is causing your error: `shim.SendBrokeredMessage(new BrokeredMessage(messageBody));`. You shouldn't be calling the shim directly. The test should be calling your code that calls `QueueClient.Send`.

Comment: I don't have time to test this right now and confirm that it is the answer, but it makes sense and seems so obvious once it's pointed out. I'll test ASAP. I assume that since you commented, you don't want all the glory for the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: That fixed it. For the sake of completeness, the above test failed once with a host look up failure (I didn't get the details) so it is not a proper deterministic test. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: I commented because it was more of a note than a definitive answer, and you probably want someone with experience in service bus for a complete answer. You can up-vote the comment if it was helpful.